# javax.naming.NamingException: Cannot create resource instance

Tags: java, oracle, datasource

I have tried a ton of variants of the below to get datasources to work but to no avail.  I have been researching/trying for a few days now so I'm throwing in the towel and asking for help.  First off though, I am having a hard time formating my code in this post. Nothing is getting indented and certain xml tags are disappearing.  Probably stupid IE that work forces us to use....

### web.xml

```
<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/nalabor</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>

<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/navarch</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

### context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Context>
  <Resource
    name="jdbc/nalabor" type="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource"
    maxActive="1" maxIdle="1" maxWait="10000" 
    factory="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSourceFactory"
    url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@####.com:1521:SID"
    driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
    username="###" password="###"/>

  <Resource
    name="jdbc/navarch" type="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource"
    maxActive="1" maxIdle="1" maxWait="10000"
    factory="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSourceFactory"
    url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@####.com:1521:SID"
    driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
    username="###" password="###"/>
</Context>
```

### Dao

```
try {      
  Context initContext = new InitialContext();
  NamingEnumeration list = initContext.list("java:/comp/env");
  System.out.println("Listing NamingEnumeration For java:/comp/env");
  while (list.hasMore()) {
    NameClassPair nc = (NameClassPair)list.next();
    System.out.println("Name Class Pair = " + nc);
  }

  list = initContext.list("java:/comp/env/jdbc");
  System.out.println("Listing NamingEnumeration java:/comp/env/jdbc");
  while (list .hasMore()) {
    NameClassPair nc = (NameClassPair)list .next();
    System.out.println("Name Class Pair = " + nc);
  }

  Context envContext = (Context) initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
  ods = (OracleDataSource) envContext.lookup("jdbc/nalabor");
} catch (Exception ex) {
  System.out.println("ERORRRRRRRR AGAIN!");
  ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

### Stack

```
Listing NamingEnumeration For java:/comp/env
Name Class Pair = mailClient: java.lang.String
Name Class Pair = siteConnCache: java.lang.String
Name Class Pair = jdbc: org.apache.naming.NamingContext
Name Class Pair = sitePOCEmail: java.lang.String
Name Class Pair = siteFilePrefix: java.lang.String
Name Class Pair = siteName: java.lang.String
Name Class Pair = siteEmail: java.lang.String

Listing NamingEnumeration java:/comp/env/jdbc
Name Class Pair = nalabor: org.apache.naming.ResourceRef
Name Class Pair = navarch: org.apache.naming.ResourceRef
ERORRRRRRRR AGAIN!
javax.naming.NamingException: Cannot create resource instance    
at org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceFactory.getObjectInstance(ResourceFactory.java:167)
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:314)
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:834)
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:181)
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:822)
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:194)
at com.gdebI.rozycki.bsc.data.LaborDAO.getWeightedLabor(LaborDAO.java:91)
at com.gdebI.rozycki.bsc.controller.action.WeightedLabor.getList(WeightedLabor.java:66)
at com.gdebI.rozycki.controller.action.ListAction.service(ListAction.java:38)
```

### WEB-INF/lib

```
ojdbc14.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you listed your resources in your web.xml but I think you are including an extra / that is causing the problem.  I've encountered this exception when the name can't be found.  Try this (Java 6+):

```
OracleDataSource ods = InitialContext.doLookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/nalabor");
```

or this for Java 5 and below:

```
InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
OracleDataSource ods = (OracleDataSource)ic.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/nalabor");
```

Comment: I put the resource in web.xml because that is something I read in a few places including on BalusC's blog here http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/07/dao-tutorial-data-layer.html#HowAboutConnectionPooling  One more thing.  yesterday I had the datasource working locally in eclipse, I was only getting the naming exception when deployed to a testing server.  Today I can't even get it to work in eclipse.

Comment: yes and no.  In Eclipse I got both mine and your code to use a datasource to connect to our Oracle server.  Deployed to our testing server neither work. Locally the extra slash had no effect, your code worked with it or without it. I could even put a double slash like this... lookup("java://comp/env/jdbc/navarch").

Comment: btw, when I removed the resource from the web.xml, I got jdbc not bound in this context, on our testing server anyways.  It didn't seem to matter with Eclipse if it was present in the web.xml or not.

Answer (score 0):

I meet this problem and I solve it .  notice your the order of elements in your web.xml. I resort the order of element in My web app's web.xml as the http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/Specifications says and it works.